# 'useState' is defined but never used EVENTHOUGH I have used useState hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-hooks, eslint

I have simple functional component like below.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import JoinRoomInputs from '../../../components/JoinRoomPage/JoinRoomInputs/JoinRoomInputs';
import { State } from '../../../store/states/states';

interface Props {
    isRoomHost: boolean;
}

const JoinRoomContent = ({ isRoomHost }:Props) => {
    const [roomIdValue, setRoomIdValue] = useState('');
    const [nameValue, setNameValue] = useState('');
    return (
        <>
            <JoinRoomInputs roomIdValue={roomIdValue} setRoomIdValue={setRoomIdValue} nameValue={nameValue} setNameValue={setNameValue} isRoomHost={isRoomHost} />
        </>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state:State) => {
    return {
        ...state
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(JoinRoomContent);
```

as you can see I have used `useState` hook in **two lines**.
But I'm getting yellow warning saying this.

```
src\components\JoinRoomPage\JoinRoomContent\JoinRoomContent.tsx
  Line 1:17:  'useState' is defined but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.

To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

And what is more curious is line 17 is this `);`

This doesn't make any sense to me.

What am I doing wrong here ?

below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.36",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.14",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.20",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript-plugin-css-modules": "^3.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a stale dev server/linter? Have you killed all watchers and local dev servers and restarted the build?

Comment: the clue is in this 'Line 1:17:'. You are not using it on line 1. So its probably not about useState but about something else broken and some odd error handling.  A true typescript error will give you correct line position. Try stripping back this component to smoke test the real error.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your server or kill the port with the following command:

```
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:PORT)
```

Answer (score 0):

The JoinRoomInputs you are importing needs to be on a separate file and with the use of props you can call it into the use state function.

If you succesfully link both using the dot notation, you will get a desired output.

Answer (score -1):

run your react app with below command:

```
npm run start
```

or try with second way:

```
npm start
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).